CSS issue with positioning and alignment in custom section
I'm working on a custom section for a Shopify website where I have a specific layout requirement. However, I'm facing issues with the positioning and alignment of elements within the section. Below is the code of my section:

<style>
  .custom-section {
    height: 650px;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #D6F1FA 0%, #C5EAF7 100%);
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .custom-section .container-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 1510px;
    height: 430px;
    top: 100px;
    left: 75px;
  }

  .custom-section .text-section {
    width: 520px;
    height: 190px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  

  .custom-section .title-container h2 {
    font-family: 'ITC Garamond Std';
    font-size: 64px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 70px;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .custom-section .text-container {
    font-family: 'iCiel Internacional', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 26px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 60%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }

  .custom-section .images-wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    height: 430px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 625px;
    display: flex;
    gap: 30px;
  }

  .custom-section .images-wrapper img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 430px;
  }

  .circular span {
    font: 26px Monaco, MonoSpace;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0;
    transform-origin: bottom center;
  }

  .circular {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
  }

  .char1 { transform: rotate(12deg); }
  .char2 { transform: rotate(24deg); }
  .char3 { transform: rotate(36deg); }
  .char4 { transform: rotate(48deg); }
  .char5 { transform: rotate(60deg); }
  .char6 { transform: rotate(72deg); }
  .char7 { transform: rotate(84deg); }
  .char8 { transform: rotate(96deg); }
  .char9 { transform: rotate(108deg); }
  .char10 { transform: rotate(120deg); }
  .char11 { transform: rotate(132deg); }
  .char12 { transform: rotate(144deg); }

  .char13 { transform: rotate(156deg); }
  .char14 { transform: rotate(168deg); }
  .char15 { transform: rotate(180deg); }
  .char16 { transform: rotate(192deg); }
  .char17 { transform: rotate(204deg); }
  .char18 { transform: rotate(216deg); }
  .char19 { transform: rotate(228deg); }
  .char20 { transform: rotate(240deg); }
  .char21 { transform: rotate(252deg); }
  .char22 { transform: rotate(264deg); }
  .char23 { transform: rotate(276deg); }
  .char24 { transform: rotate(288deg); }

  .char25 { transform: rotate(300deg); }
  .char26 { transform: rotate(312deg); }
  .char27 { transform: rotate(324deg); }
  .char28 { transform: rotate(336deg); }
  .char29 { transform: rotate(348deg); }
  .char30 { transform: rotate(360deg); }
  .char31 { transform: rotate(372deg); }
  .char32 { transform: rotate(384deg); }
  .char33 { transform: rotate(396deg); }
  .char34 { transform: rotate(408deg); }
  .char35 { transform: rotate(420deg); }
  .char36 { transform: rotate(432deg); }

  .char37 { transform: rotate(444deg); }
  .char38 { transform: rotate(456deg); }
  .char39 { transform: rotate(468deg); }
</style>

<script src="{{ 'custom-section.js' | asset_url }}" defer="defer"></script>


<section class="custom-section">
  <div class="container-wrapper">
    <div class="text-section">
      <div class="title-container">
        <h2>Our jewelry</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="text-container">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tempor tincidunt posuere. Nam tempus, leo ac tempus hendrerit.</p>
      </div>


  
    </div>

    
    <div class="images-wrapper">
      <img src="{{ 'image1.jpg' | asset_url }}" alt="Image 1">
      <img src="{{ 'image2.jpg' | asset_url }}" alt="Image 2">
      <img src="{{ 'image3.jpg' | asset_url }}" alt="Image 3">
    </div>
  </div>

  <h1 class="circular">
    <span class="char1">W</span>
    <span class="char2">e</span>
    <span class="char3">'</span>
    <span class="char4">r</span>
    <span class="char5">e</span>
    
    <span class="char6">t</span>
    <span class="char7">h</span>
    <span class="char8">e</span>
    
    <span class="char9">b</span>
    <span class="char10">e</span>
    <span class="char11">s</span>
    <span class="char12">t</span>
    <span class="char13">i</span>
    <span class="char14">e</span>
    
    <span class="char15">t</span>
    <span class="char16">h</span>
    <span class="char17">a</span>
    <span class="char18">t</span>
    
    <span class="char19">y</span>
    <span class="char20">o</span>
    <span class="char21">u</span>
    
    <span class="char22">c</span>
    <span class="char23">a</span>
    <span class="char24">n</span>

    <span class="char25">b</span>
    <span class="char26">e</span>

    <span class="char27">y</span>
    <span class="char28">o</span>
    <span class="char29">u</span>
    <span class="char30">r</span>
    <span class="char31">s</span>
    <span class="char32">e</span>
    <span class="char33">l</span>
    <span class="char34">f</span>

    <span class="char35">w</span>
    <span class="char36">i</span>
    <span class="char37">t</span>
    <span class="char38">h</span>
    <span class="char39">.</span>
  </h1>

</section>

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Custom section",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "text",
      "label": "Text"
    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "name": "Default custom section"
    }
  ],
  "tag": "section",
  "class": "custom-section",
  "limit": 1
}
{% endschema %}



And this is the "custom-section.js":

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const text = document.querySelector('.circular');

  const message = "hello beautiful world";

  text.innerHTML = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
    let circularTextSpan = document.createElement('span');
    circularTextSpan.textContent = message[i];
    text.appendChild(circularTextSpan);
    circularTextSpan.style.transform = `rotate(${360 * i / message.length}deg)`;
  }
});



Current Issue:
The layout is not aligning as expected based on my design mockup. Specifically, I'm having trouble with:

Positioning of the .text-section and .images-wrapper relative to .container-wrapper.
Alignment and spacing of the circular text () with respect to other elements in the section.
Any adjustments needed to ensure responsive behavior across different screen sizes.

Expected Outcome:
I want the section to match the design mockup precisely, with proper alignment and spacing of text and images within .container-wrapper, and the circular text () positioned correctly without overlap or misalignment.
Screenshots:
Current Appearance: Current Appearance
Desired Appearance: Desired Appearance
Any insights or suggestions on how to achieve the desired layout would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here’s a start on your first two bullet points. After running this snippet, use the full page link to see the results properly.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  const text = document.querySelector('.circular');

  const message = "We’re the bestie that you can be yourself with. ";

  text.innerHTML = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
    let circularTextSpan = document.createElement('span');
    circularTextSpan.textContent = message[i];
    text.appendChild(circularTextSpan);
    circularTextSpan.style.transform = `rotate(${360 * i / message.length}deg)`;
  }
});
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.custom-section {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #D6F1FA 0%, #C5EAF7 100%);
  position: relative;
  padding: 100px 0 100px 75px;
}

.custom-section .container-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 1510px;
  height: 430px;
  border: 2px dashed red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.custom-section .text-section {
  width: 520px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
}

.custom-section .title-container h2 {
  font-family: 'ITC Garamond Std';
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 70px;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.custom-section .text-container {
  font-family: 'iCiel Internacional', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 60%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.custom-section .spacer {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px dashed green;
}

.custom-section .images-wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  height: 430px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 625px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
  border: 2px dashed purple;
}

.custom-section .images-wrapper img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 430px;
}

.circular span {
  font: 13px Monaco, MonoSpace;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 75px;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}

.circular {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border: 2px dashed yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.char1 { transform: rotate(12deg); }
.char2 { transform: rotate(24deg); }
.char3 { transform: rotate(36deg); }
.char4 { transform: rotate(48deg); }
.char5 { transform: rotate(60deg); }
.char6 { transform: rotate(72deg); }
.char7 { transform: rotate(84deg); }
.char8 { transform: rotate(96deg); }
.char9 { transform: rotate(108deg); }
.char10 { transform: rotate(120deg); }
.char11 { transform: rotate(132deg); }
.char12 { transform: rotate(144deg); }

.char13 { transform: rotate(156deg); }
.char14 { transform: rotate(168deg); }
.char15 { transform: rotate(180deg); }
.char16 { transform: rotate(192deg); }
.char17 { transform: rotate(204deg); }
.char18 { transform: rotate(216deg); }
.char19 { transform: rotate(228deg); }
.char20 { transform: rotate(240deg); }
.char21 { transform: rotate(252deg); }
.char22 { transform: rotate(264deg); }
.char23 { transform: rotate(276deg); }
.char24 { transform: rotate(288deg); }

.char25 { transform: rotate(300deg); }
.char26 { transform: rotate(312deg); }
.char27 { transform: rotate(324deg); }
.char28 { transform: rotate(336deg); }
.char29 { transform: rotate(348deg); }
.char30 { transform: rotate(360deg); }
.char31 { transform: rotate(372deg); }
.char32 { transform: rotate(384deg); }
.char33 { transform: rotate(396deg); }
.char34 { transform: rotate(408deg); }
.char35 { transform: rotate(420deg); }
.char36 { transform: rotate(432deg); }

.char37 { transform: rotate(444deg); }
.char38 { transform: rotate(456deg); }
.char39 { transform: rotate(468deg); }
<section class="custom-section">
  <div class="container-wrapper">
    <div class="text-section">
      <div class="title-container">
        <h2>Our jewelry</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="text-container">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tempor tincidunt posuere. Nam tempus, leo ac tempus hendrerit.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <h1 class="circular">
        <span class="char1">W</span>
        <span class="char2">e</span>
        <span class="char3">'</span>
        <span class="char4">r</span>
        <span class="char5">e</span>

        <span class="char6">t</span>
        <span class="char7">h</span>
        <span class="char8">e</span>

        <span class="char9">b</span>
        <span class="char10">e</span>
        <span class="char11">s</span>
        <span class="char12">t</span>
        <span class="char13">i</span>
        <span class="char14">e</span>

        <span class="char15">t</span>
        <span class="char16">h</span>
        <span class="char17">a</span>
        <span class="char18">t</span>

        <span class="char19">y</span>
        <span class="char20">o</span>
        <span class="char21">u</span>

        <span class="char22">c</span>
        <span class="char23">a</span>
        <span class="char24">n</span>

        <span class="char25">b</span>
        <span class="char26">e</span>

        <span class="char27">y</span>
        <span class="char28">o</span>
        <span class="char29">u</span>
        <span class="char30">r</span>
        <span class="char31">s</span>
        <span class="char32">e</span>
        <span class="char33">l</span>
        <span class="char34">f</span>

        <span class="char35">w</span>
        <span class="char36">i</span>
        <span class="char37">t</span>
        <span class="char38">h</span>
        <span class="char39">.</span>
      </h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class="images-wrapper">
      <img src="http://picsum.photos/500">
      <img src="http://picsum.photos/501">
      <img src="http://picsum.photos/502">
    </div>

  </div>

</section>

<!--
{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Custom section",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "text",
      "label": "Text"
    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "name": "Default custom section"
    }
  ],
  "tag": "section",
  "class": "custom-section",
  "limit": 1
}
{% endschema %}
-->




Thank you so much for your valuable answer! I really appreciate it!
The only thing is that I want to make the 'h1' with the circular text to not be in the 'container-wrapper'. It should be outside it, but in the same position in which it is now.
Can you help me with that?

Why do you want it to be outside?

In the figma file that they provided me, it is outside.

Also, I will ask you one more question. :)
In the description of the task, they wrote "The page should be customizable from the Theme Customizer.". But I developed this section from scratch and when I go to the customizer, I can not edit this section. Am I did something wrong?
What do you think?

I think you have accepted a job which you do not have the skills to deliver. Read the documentation.
